# How to override get_context_data properly in class based views?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I use `get_context_method` in my DetailView class to get a `pk` value needed for my query. But now I cant get `object` values in my template, cause `get_context_method` just override them. Is there any other way to get a `pk` key in DetailView? Or how to not override `object` values?
In other words, how to make this work properly?

```
##views.py
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        id = int(self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        props = Statistics.objects.filter(user=id, property=100)
        extra_context = {'user_property':props}
        return extra_context
```

Template:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1>{{ object.user.full_name }}</h1>
        <h5>Property</h5>
        <div class="flex-container">
          <div class="flex-scores">
          <ul class="scores">
              <li>{{user_property}}
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override `get_context_data` and get the value returned by the super method, yet you define a new dictionary and return that. Instead you want to add your extra context to the dictionary returned by the super method:

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        id = int(self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        props = Statistics.objects.filter(user=id, property=100)
        context['user_property'] = props
        # OR
        # context.update({'user_property':props})
        return context
```