# Django CBV inheritance not working as expected

Tags: django, django-views

I use these two classes to get the context data and check permissions respectively:

```
class RestaurantView(View):
    def get_context_data(self):
        ctx = {'restaurant': get_object_or_404(Restaurant, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])}
        return ctx

class ManageRestaurantMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, RestaurantView):
    def test_func(self):
        ctx = super().get_context_data()
        return ctx['restaurant'].owner == self.request.user
```

Now the first one is working, so when i don't need permission i get the expected behavior, for example with this `DetailView`:

```
class Info(RestaurantView, DetailView):
    model = Restaurant
    context_object_name = 'restaurant'
    template_name = 'restaurant/info.html'
```

But then if inherit from `ManageRestaurantMixin` the permissions are checked as expected, but the context object is not working and the template displays an empty form:

```
class EditInfo(ManageRestaurantMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Restaurant
    context_object_name = 'restaurant'
    template_name = 'restaurant/edit_info.html'
    fields = ['name', 'address', 'logo']
    success_url = '/account/myrestaurants'
```

I get that the context gets overwritten, but i don't get how.

1. How can i solve this?
2. Is there a better way to handle this kind of situations?

Edit:

*edit_info.html*:

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="update">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `super().get_context_data()` in the `RestaurantView.get_context_data`?

Comment: @vinkomlacic Yes i tried, but no luck

Comment: @JacopoDT When you say the template displays an empty form, does it have the correct input fields and field names?

Comment: @evergreen I should have been more specific: no the form is empty without the input fields and field names. There is only the submit button (which is hard-coded in the template). I post the it for completeness

Comment: @JacopoDT Django puts the form in `context_data`, and it is getting overwritten by `RestaurantView.get_context_data`. As @vinkomlacic said, you need to get the original context with `ctx = super().get_context_data()` then add `ctx['restaurant'] = ...` and finally `return ctx`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override get\_context\_data properly in class based views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191888/how-to-override-get-context-data-properly-in-class-based-views)

Comment: Why do you even need that `RestaurantView` class of yours? Both of the views you use it in would add the object to the context even without that.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat >Does this answer your question? Yes and no. I don't like to override `get_context_data` in every subclass. I'm probably overthinking it. Would set an attribute `self.restaurant` in RestaurantView be a good solution? What do you think?
> Why do you even need that RestaurantView? I also use that for other restaurant related Views

Comment: You don't need to override it in every subclass. The point is you aren't overriding it properly. If you read the linked duplicate carefully, you need to call `super` and add your extra context to the returned dictionary and return that. (Also as I said these specific views you have shared don't need to inherit from that class, `restaurant` is already added to the context automatically by Django in those 2 views)

Comment: I'm getting `'EditInfo' object has no attribute 'object'` from doing that